# Proof that if $3^n - 2^n$ is prime then $n$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

This was a question from a previous year in a test and I couldn't solve it yet.

> If $3^n - 2^n$ is prime, then $n$ must be prime.

Do you have any tips, suggestions?

Comment: If $a\mid b$, then $3^a-2^a$ is a divisor of $3^b-2^b$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose that $n$ is composite, say $n = ab$. Then 
$$ 3^n - 2^n = (3^a)^b - (2^a)^b,$$
and
$$x^b - y^b = (x -y) (x^{b-1} + x^{b-2}y + \cdots + y^{b-1}).$$
Taking $x = 3^a$, $y = 2^a$ gives a non-trivial factorization of $3^n - 2^n$.
Hence if $n$ is composite, then $3^n - 2^n$ is as well.

Comment: welp, I'm stupid. Thank you! I will remove this post in a bit to stop embarassing myself. Have a good day!

Comment: No, don't remove the post.  Your answerer spent effort and got 5 upvotes for it.  Don't rob him of his points.  Embarasmunt is good for us.

Comment: And so is embarrassment.

Comment: alright, a shame that this is my first post on this beautiful site. Amazing comunity as well!